# Cross-platform video player that allows caching for offline but protects against unauthorised retention of videos

Tags: video, offline, cross-platform

I'm looking for a video player that would act as the client for some secure video distribution platform. The security we want is:

1. Authorised-access only
2. Caching videos for offline play without them easily keeping the videos if they are deauthorised

We need to support both Windows 8+ (7 if possible) and the latest Mac OS X. Also it can't be some backwater piece of software - preference is for a popular solution that's on a major distribution platform like the Mac App Store.

I've seen [Ultratube](http://www.ultratube.it) for iOS, which seems to be close to what we want, though we need it for desktop rather than mobile.

**Update:** Ultratube isn't available for the Australian app store, so it's not really a good example. Need it to be globally available.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "protects against copyright infringement"?

Comment: @Mawg It's in the question but I tweaked the title to remove the ambiguity. Essentially we don't want the user easily keeping the videos if we deauthorise them. Obviously we can only protect so much, e.g. they could always just screen capture it, but what we don't want to do is just hand out a plain video file that they could easily hang on to forever.